# <img src="{{$product->file_path2}}"> not working Laravel 9 blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

Actually i have table in database named products where i have two photos sections. And photos, both are uploading in database with no problem but, one is not coming on site. also i checked the variable and it is not empty and also database is not empty! and here is my code

```
<div id="product-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner bg-light">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="w-100 h-100" src="../../storage/app/public/product/{{$product->file_path}}" alt="Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="w-100 h-100" src="../../storage/app/public/product/{{$product->file_path2}}" alt="Image2">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: also the src address is correct, because photos are here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mSXGhNCx?fbclid=IwAR2eVEgPTGbDQyGpTVjmnRMPylqriqg3wzjXjMh_GUClnCfcX5gPqUCL3YU

Comment: Without controller and model it's very hard to help you.

Comment: try this <img src="{{asset('product')}}/{{$product->file_path1}}">

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Run command to check : `php artisan storage:link`

```
<img class="w-100 h-100" src="{{ asset('storage/product/' . $product->file_path) }}" alt="Image">
```